# how to index website data contents in database for making a website word search?

Tags: java, search, solr, indexing, search-engine

I want to implement a website word search (user searches about a word and gets the sentences which include the word from the specific website) in java MYSELF (without using lucandra,solr,nutch,... I mean),till now I can get content (text,not the source code) of website with the help of jsoup,but I don't know how to index the datas in the database,I searched google to understand about algorithms which well known indexers such as solr use,I have understood some things such as using inverted list or hashtable,... but they are so in general,I want to know exactly what should I do?

I want to use cassandra as my db,so I read about cassandra secondry indexing,but I have to know more about it,is this really what I should focus on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what should be my scenario to implement a website word search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210682/what-should-be-my-scenario-to-implement-a-website-word-search)

Comment: no this is absolutely different.